# When did BlackStar and Tsubaki swap?

Tags: soul-eater

In the second episode of Soul Eater, during BlackStar's fight with Mifune BlackStar, Tsubaki used *Shadow Star* to swap places with BlackStar and disguise herself while BlackStar attacked Mifune's blind spot.

Just before this, Mifune noticed BlackStar (apparently now Tsubaki) is a different person from the way he was breathing. He also commented that BlackStar's eye colour had changed.

So when exactly (episode time) did BlackStar and Tsubaki swap? Was BlackStar's eye color different at that moment or did it change suddenly later? And if it changed later, when was that?

*NOTE: I ask this question as every time I re-watch the episode, I'm engrossed in the fight and keep missing it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there will be evidence to back this up, however when Black Star says "Tsubaki.. Ninja-to mode!" and a burst of smoke appears (around **16:27**), is practically the only chance they could switch - and it makes perfect sense.

Within this puff of smoke, Black Star makes his 'escape' to a better position, and instead of Tsubaki changing into Ninja-to form, **she becomes the dummy**.

I doubt that Mifune saying that his eye colors changed was quite true, or at least can't be verified by the viewers, as Black Star doesn't have colored eyes - just typical black dots. Tsubaki, on the other hand, has the 'other' style of anime-eyes, (which are a shade of blue).

The *important part* is, however, that when Tsubaki is in Dummy-form, her eyes were the same as Black Star's, as proven when the dummy 'floats away' (it is very clear to see the eyes changing from Blackstar's to Tsubaki's).